# Loading .png to Bitmap

Tags: bitmap, f#, png

I need to access pixels of a .png file through F#.

I can load it into an Image by its `FromFile` method, but I can't access its pixels. I don't know how to turn an Image into a Bitmap. Where I could use a `GetPixel` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the image directly into a Bitmap object:

```
let img = "C:\\MyImages\\MyImage.png"
let bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(img)
```

From there on you can use the methods and properties of Bitmap on the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert an `Image` to a `Bitmap` with

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap(loadedimage)
```